# Превышение лимита динамических запросов

Tags: c++, mysql

Дано: СУБД `Mysql`, стандартный `connector mysql` для `C++`
Что происходит : периодически достигаю максимального значения `max_prepared_stmt_count`, что приводит к ошибке `Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements`, как следствие база какое то время недоступна для чтения/записи. 
В приложении очень много запросов которые постоянно что-то пишут в базу. 
Работаю с этим так :

```
  sql::Statement *stmt;
    stmt = mysql_vector[std::this_thread::get_id()]->con->createStatement();
    stmt->execute(USE_DB);

    sql::PreparedStatement *prep_stmt;

    try
    {
        prep_stmt = mysql_vector[std::this_thread::get_id()]->con->prepareStatement("update staff  set  pos=?;");
        prep_stmt->setInt(1, account);

        prep_stmt->execute();
        stmt->close();
        prep_stmt->close();
        delete stmt;
        delete prep_stmt;
        return true;
    }
    catch (exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << "insert_staff: " << e.what() << endl;
        stmt->close();
        prep_stmt->close();
        delete stmt;
        delete prep_stmt;
        return false;
    }
```

Т.к. приходисят работать в многопоточном окружении, использую одно и тоже подключение для поток это про `mysql_vector[std::this_thread::get_id()]->con->createStatement();`

Как быть с превышением лимита запросов ?? сейчас параметр установлен на ~341 млн.

Comment: Читал на форумах, что якобы отказ от задания параметров через такую конструкцию 'prep_stmt->setInt(1, account);'  может решить проблему, но что-то не вериться.

Comment: может у вас база не справляется с нагрузкой, нет?

Comment: @VTT, что вы подразумеваете под не справляется с нагрузкой?

Comment: ну как, если лимит из 341 млн запросов исчерпывается, то значит обрабатываться они не успевают, нет?

Comment: Конфиг у базы посути дефолтный, кроме параметров на число конектов и запросов. Что нужно делать и куда смотреть, что бы выявить проблему? Гугления по этому коду ошибки все говорят увеличь лимит и поменяй формирование запросов, описал в комменте выше, но это костыли.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте исправить утечки памяти и незакрытые объекты в этом фрагменте.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86638/discussion-between-alex-b-and-vtt).